# Docker Swarm - some task containers are not being updated on deploy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm using Docker 18.05 with Docker Swarm to deploy a service with several tasks with a rolling update. Occasionally, 1 out of 3 tasks is not being updated with the latest version.
After reading on this issue, I added tagging to the image in the docker compose file to ensure it pulls the latest image. I also moved to Amazon ECR instead of the local registry, but it didn't fix the problem.

It's a bit abstract question but I've no idea how to fix it. 
In addition, are there any deployment logs that can help me understand of the tasks have received the update?

Deployment code:

```
sudo docker-compose build
sudo docker-compose push
sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml --prune --resolve-image always --with-registry-auth my_stack
```

Compose config (the relevant part):

```
web:
    restart: always
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      update_config:
        delay: 10s 
      restart_policy:
        condition: any      
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
```

Service inspect:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 510
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2018-06-01T21:49:43.34465496Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2018-06-02T00:19:14.379304654Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "my_stack_webserver",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "my_stack"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19@sha256:f7e1f4746703c537449b6c1c7c6ee5c55ada3b8e564de5575a83a76c3188f8a6",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "my_stack"
                    },
                    "Args": [
                        "bash",
                        "-c",
                        "python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput \u0026\u0026 python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput \u0026\u0026 gunicorn -c /code/gunicorn_conf.py app_reader.wsgi:application"
                    ],
                    "Env": [
                    ],
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "volume",
                            "Source": "my_stack_log-data",
                            "Target": "/home/log_data",
                            "VolumeOptions": {
                                "Labels": {
                                    "com.docker.stack.namespace": "my_stack"
                                },
                                "DriverConfig": {
                                    "Name": "local"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Constraints": [
                        "node.role == manager"
                    ],
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "l28idb1gahjv5jzqtf0xtkauz",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "my_web"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 3
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "Delay": 10000000000,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9000,
                        "PublishedPort": 9000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 9000,
                        "PublishedPort": 9000,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 9000,
                    "PublishedPort": 9000,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "xw3mgpih0btibuoixvhmlm8cl",
                    "Addr": "10.255.0.4/16"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "l28idb1gahjv5jzqtf0xtkauz",
                    "Addr": "10.0.0.4/24"
                }
            ]
        },
        "UpdateStatus": {
            "State": "updating",
            "StartedAt": "2018-06-02T00:19:14.379283065Z",
            "Message": "update in progress"
        }
    }
]
```

UPDATE:
I removed the restart and the restart policy and it didn't solve the problem.
I also tried adding `order: start-first` to the config and it did fix the problem but for some reason I have 1 second downtime when the 2nd container is being updated.

This is the docker event log:

```
2018-06-05T19:00:12.288664241Z service update sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw (image.new=xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-05-19-00, image.old=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-05-18-49, name=my_stack_web)
2018-06-05T19:00:12.292079302Z service update sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw (name=my_stack_web, updatestate.new=updating)
2018-06-05T19:00:12.510796471Z container create 5763d590cec1ec721e3d006b2ae80c089aa7c6a71ceef94d1b33b74bbc21f0ea (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=3tnyzawizq3m8a7q6oyddjxoj, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.3tnyzawizq3m8a7q6oyddjxoj, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-05-19-00@sha256:55025c54a45459d7d2460b4fcbd97498c482db0b0571c36a286b8c343214c145, name=my_stack_web.3.3tnyzawizq3m8a7q6oyddjxoj)
2018-06-05T19:00:13.298951303Z container create 93aeec4d847c0fbcdb2b1bd968b46cb40ccf5e728a481dfd309a9662c1125e1f (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=2bx8d8825ls5dkjg4um9a3k01, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.2bx8d8825ls5dkjg4um9a3k01, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-05-19-00@sha256:55025c54a45459d7d2460b4fcbd97498c482db0b0571c36a286b8c343214c145, name=my_stack_web.3.2bx8d8825ls5dkjg4um9a3k01)
2018-06-05T19:00:13.851025262Z container start 93aeec4d847c0fbcdb2b1bd968b46cb40ccf5e728a481dfd309a9662c1125e1f (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=2bx8d8825ls5dkjg4um9a3k01, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.2bx8d8825ls5dkjg4um9a3k01, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-05-19-00@sha256:55025c54a45459d7d2460b4fcbd97498c482db0b0571c36a286b8c343214c145, name=my_stack_web.3.2bx8d8825ls5dkjg4um9a3k01)
2018-06-05T19:00:15.256815506Z container destroy 5763d590cec1ec721e3d006b2ae80c089aa7c6a71ceef94d1b33b74bbc21f0ea (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=3tnyzawizq3m8a7q6oyddjxoj, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.3tnyzawizq3m8a7q6oyddjxoj, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-05-19-00@sha256:55025c54a45459d7d2460b4fcbd97498c482db0b0571c36a286b8c343214c145, name=my_stack_web.3.3tnyzawizq3m8a7q6oyddjxoj)
2018-06-05T19:00:15.470736086Z container kill 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, signal=15)
2018-06-05T19:00:15.714691366Z container kill 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, signal=15)
2018-06-05T19:00:25.482250914Z container kill 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, signal=9)
2018-06-05T19:00:25.559283083Z container die 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, exitCode=137, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y)
2018-06-05T19:00:25.818572261Z container stop 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y)
2018-06-05T19:00:25.818598479Z container stop 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y)
2018-06-05T19:00:25.846005241Z container destroy 6d2ecb46065cc5d04b3f24a120c60e892d670b0b1cdd0c95812f760777f4df32 (com.docker.stack.namespace=my_stack, com.docker.swarm.node.id=kf9xehdk4zws2ufl3ouu8l4gr, com.docker.swarm.service.id=sj0mx9wzwec3totulzx1nrzrw, com.docker.swarm.service.name=my_stack_web, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, com.docker.swarm.task.name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y, image=xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webserver:2018-06-02-00-19, name=my_stack_web.3.xjh1ds0gkf14g6mxw9zz0lp1y)
```

Comment: Please include output of your service ps, inspect on the service, and inspect on each of the tasks.

Comment: You don't need a restart policy on the containers when you have swarm managing the replicas. I've seen these conflict in the past where both the docker host with a down container and swarm mode are trying to start additional instances of a container.

Comment: @BMitch I added the inspect output. Unfortunately, we already forced all tasks to update so I'm not sure it's helpful. I can update the logs after our next update.
Thanks!

Comment: ‘Docker events’ is a steam of most actions the managers and nodes take (capture it on all nodes). Can you narrow it down to a single node? Is it only one service that has the issue? Did you check task history to ensure it really never stopped the old container? Might be better to troubleshoot this in Docker forums rather then a q&a site

Comment: The issue is always with the same service (so far...). Is there a way to get the deploy command logs? I can see the old container when I run `service ps`

Comment: the ‘Docker events’ had history. See the command options. But it’s only 1000 lines I think

Comment: I updated the question with the docker events log. looks like just one container is starting but I don't know why

Comment: Were you able to gather inspect output from each of the tasks when you reproduced the issue?

Comment: Yes. You can see the inspect in my question. The last line might be relevant `"Message": "update in progress"` but I don't know what's stopping the update